# mpeg format play in command line using Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, mpeg

Im using this below command to play a ts file . but it is only opening the video file and standing in pause position not playing at all . What may be the reason .

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=4M.ts ! tsdemux name=dmx ! queue2  ! faad ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink  dmx. ! queue2  ! mpegvideoparse ! mpeg2dec ! videoscale  ! xvimagesink
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=4M.ts ! tsdemux name=dmx ! queue  ! audio/mpeg ! mpegaudioparse ! mad ! alsasink dmx. ! queue ! mpegvideoparse ! mpeg2dec ! videoscale ! xvimagesink
```

After i use the above pipeline its working . Thank you